# Trouble with Angular $q.all()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory which is making 'n' number of $http request and to fulfill this I am using $q.all() , so let me show you my factory code.

```js
app.factory('loadBooks',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){
  var promises = [];
    return {

        getBooks : function(category,no){
          for(var i =1; i<=no; i++){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

                 console.log(i + 'request');
                 $http.get(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/${category}?page=${i}&pageSize=10`)
                 .then(function(response){
                  deferred.resolve(response);
                  console.log(response);
                })

        .catch(function(response){
          deferred.reject(response);
        })
        
        promises.push(deferred);
      
        }

          return $q.all(promises);
          
        }
      }

}])
```

And this is my controller from where i am calling the factory function

```js
app.controller('bookController',['$scope','loadBooks','$routeParams',function($scope,loadBooks,$routeParams){
    $scope.count = $routeParams.no;
    loadBooks.getBooks('books',2).then(function(data){
          $scope.books = data;   
       })
       .catch(function(response){
       });
    }]);
```

Now the problem is I am making 2 request from the getBooks method and the api is sending me data for both the request but for some reason the first request pushes no data inside the promise array but the second does. I dont know what i am doing wrong. The api is working fine because I can see the data coming in my network tab but data from first request is not getting pushed inside the promise array!
I would be thankful if you could tell me what the problem is. Btw I am new to $q.

Comment: In addition to the answer, it should originally be `promises.push(deferred.promise)`. `promises.push(deferred)` isn't supposed to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've fallen prey to an insidious bug called "closing over the loop variable". The value of the `deferred` variable changes in every iteration of the loop, so when this eventually executes:

```
deferred.resolve(response);
```

`deferred` is referring to the *last* value that the `deferred` variable took on.

On top of that, you're using the Explicit Promise Creation Antipattern, an antipattern that causes your promise code to be unnecessarily convoluted and error prone.

Solve both problems by using promises the way they're supposed to be used:

```js
app.factory('loadBooks', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getBooks: function(category, no) {
      var promises = [];

      for (var i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        console.log(i + 'request');
        promises.push(
            $http.get(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/${category}?page=${i}&pageSize=10`)
        );
      }

      return $q.all(promises);
    }
  }

}])
```

Comment: haha thank you, you saved me man ! I gotta learn more about $q I guess.

Comment: @iAmRoot Here's some good reading: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/ and this https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns. The page in the first link refers to what you were doing here as the "forgotten promise".